# How to decode Mac serial number without using external services?

Tags: macos, serial-number

On my app, I would like to get the mac specs through the serial number without using external services.

Is there a documentation for this? There are a lot of sites that do that, but how?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What specs are you referring to exactly?

Comment: CPU, memory, model, production year, etc. Like the site http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com/Desktop/index.php do, for example